# Возврат нескольких строк из созданной функции

Tags: python, python-3.x

Разбираю упражнение "Викторина" из книжки. Программа должна читать из текстового файла строки.Я сделал функцию, которая открывает файл. Потом функцию, которая читает строку. Затем - строку которая должна выводить блок с несколькими строками, и вот здесь непонятно. Функция, которая должна выводить блок строк, возвращает все строки одним списком

> Вывод:('Эпизод от которого вы не сможете отказаться\n', 'Вообразим, что вы гангстер, которого сдали сообщники. Вы конечно, \nрешаете удариться .........)

Но если я делаю отображение не через функцию, а именно:

```
print (next_line(the_file))
print (next_line(the_file))
print (next_line(the_file))
```

то все получается нормально

> Вывод(нужный вариант): (Эпизод от которого вы не сможете отказаться
>
> Вообразим, что вы гангстер, которого сдали сообщники. Вы конечно, 
>   решаете удариться в бега. Какое животное вы 
>   могли бы упомянуть, если бы вам пришлось скрываться очень долго?)

Если из функции я вывожу один параметр, то тип вывода str, но если же вывожу несколько через запятую то тип вывода получается tuple.

Вопрос: Каким образом можно вывести из функции несколько элементов чтобы получилось как во втором, нужном варианте?

код:

```
# функция open file - открывает файл
# если файла нет то говорит о том что невозможно открыть
def open_file(name,mode):
    '''открывает файл'''
    try:
       the_file = open(name,mode,encoding='utf-8')
    except IOError as e:
        print('невозможно открыть файл',name,'работа программы будет 
завершена\n',e)
        input('нажмите энтер чтобы выйти')
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print('файл',name,'открыт')
        return the_file



# функция next line
# принимает файловый обьект и возвращает строку
def next_line(the_file):
    line = the_file.readline()
    line = line.replace('/','\n')
    return line


# функция next block
# читает очередной блок строк соответствующий одному вопросу
def next_bloc(the_file):
    '''возвращает очередной блок данных из игрового файла'''
    category = next_line(the_file)
    question = next_line(the_file)
    answer = []
    for i in range(4):
        answer.append(next_line(the_file))
        correct = next_line(the_file)
        if correct:
            correct = correct[0]
            explanation = next_line(the_file)
    return category,question,answer,correct,explanation

the_file = open('for_viktorina.txt','r')

def block(the_file):
    d = next_line(the_file)
    f = next_line(the_file)
    c = next_line(the_file)
    return d,f,c


print(block(the_file))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша функция `def block(the_file):` и так возвращает несколько элементов (как кортеж).

Просто, распакуйте кортеж:

```
d, f, c = block(the_file)
print(d)
print(f)
print(c)
```

---

Если нужно каждый элемент коллекции вывести на отдельной строке, то можно сделать используя только `print`:

```
print(*block(the_file), sep='\n')
```

Оператор `*` перед `block` раскладывает каждый элемент коллекции в отдельный параметр, т.е. это аналог:

```
d, f, c = block(the_file)
print(d, f, c)
```

А `sep='\n'` говорит, что значения, переданные в `print` нужно разделять символом перевода строки, а не пробелом (по умолчанию)

Comment: Спасибо.Мне интересно почему тип вывода меняется в зависимости от того сколько элементов я вывожу. Если один то (str) а если несколько то (tuple).И у автора в книге пример строится именно через функцию. То есть подразумевается что должны выводится как во втором примере.

Comment: Да. Все получилось!!!! Спасибо большое!!

Comment: При создании кортежа круглые скобки опциональные, т.е. `return d, f, c` это тоже самое что `return (d, f, c)`. 
[А чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)